# In spyder how to get back default view of running a code in Ipython console

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Hi on running a code in the console I am getting the display as:

> > runfile('C:/Users/DX/Desktop/me template/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/praCTICE.py', wdir='C:/Users/DX/Desktop/me template/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing')

and on viewing a small matrix it is showing up as

> array([['France', 44.0, 72000.0],
>          ['Spain', 27.0, 48000.0],
>          ['Germany', 30.0, 54000.0],
>          ..., 
>          ['France', 48.0, 79000.0],
>          ['Germany', 50.0, 83000.0],
>          ['France', 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)

Even though the matrix is pity small how to change it to get the default view when i cun my codes in ipython console 
I installed the latest version of anaconda

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) Please use the Variable Explorer to visualize Numpy arrays and Pandas DataFrames. That's its main purpose.

Comment: Didnt get it my how will i view it ...data frame is showing up.  but X is object its not showing up on clicking and well typing x is not showing  me full data  .